# Display days between statuses listed horizontally

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have the following table which represents the operation details for a ticketing database. What I want to do is display horizontally the last 10 distinct operations on each ticket with the date difference (in days) between each status compared with the previous.

This is the raw table:

```
Case_number Operation_Name  Date
112345      Canceled        22.04.2018
112345      On hold         20.04.2018
112345      On hold         15.04.2018
112345      Processing      10.04.2018
112345      Open            08.04.2018
112347      Closed          21.04.2018
112347      On hold         20.04.2018
112347      On hold         18.04.2018
112347      Processing      15.04.2018
112347      Processing      13.04.2018
112347      Open            11.04.2018
```

The output should look like this

[image]

As you can see:

```
112347      On hold         20.04.2018
112347      On hold         18.04.2018
```

there could be a repeating status for which i have to extract only the first date (18.04.2018).

I tried with the lead function but I had no luck.

Thank you in advance for your time and ideas guys!

Comment: Is it possible to have the same status multiple times with other values inbetween, e.g. `Processing` - `On hold` - `Processing`?

Comment: Yes, it is possible and in that case the two statuses "processing" (as shown in your example) are taken into account as different statuses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will remove additional rows with the same status and assigne a sequence number:

```
with cte as 
 (
   select *,
      lead(Operation_Name) -- previous Operation_Name
      over (partition by case_number
            order by Dat desc) as prev_op
   from tab
 )
select cte.*, 
   datediff(day
           ,date
           ,lag(date) -- next date
            over (partition by case_number
                  order by Date desc)
           ) as days_between,
   row_number()
   over (partition by case_number
         order by Date desc) as rn
from cte
where prev_op <> Operation_Name -- different value
   or prev_op is null           -- or first row
;
```

Now you can pass this to PIVOT or do the old-syle max(case):

```
with cte as 
 (
   select *,
      lead(Operation_Name) -- previous Operation_Name
      over (partition by case_number
            order by Date desc) as prev_op
   from tab
 )
, cte2 as
 (
   select cte.*, 
      datediff(day
              ,date
              ,lag(date) -- previous Operation_Name
               over (partition by case_number
                     order by Date desc)
) as days_between,
      row_number()
      over (partition by case_number
            order by Date desc) as rn
   from cte
   where prev_op <> Operation_Name -- different value
      or prev_op is null           -- or first row
 )
select case_number,
   max(case when rn = 1 then Operation_Name end),
   max(case when rn = 2 then Operation_Name end),
   max(case when rn = 2 then days_between end),
   max(case when rn = 3 then Operation_Name end),
   max(case when rn = 3 then days_between end),
   max(case when rn = 4 then Operation_Name end),
   max(case when rn = 4 then days_between end)
from cte2
group by case_number
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this as a straight up SQL query, but requires some elbow grease.

Basically, we need to 
1. Establish row order for each case_number and 
2. Do a double pivot operation to get the Operation_Name column and Days_Elapsed column into per one column each by step

See below for a solution where up to 4 steps are handled. It is trivial to modify this to add more steps if you need 10. Play with the CTE and intermediate results to understand the steps in formulating this.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2097b/1)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
create table test (id int, status varchar(max), date datetime)

insert test values 
(1, 'cancelled', '2018-04-07'),
(1, 'hold', '2018-04-05'),
(1, 'processing', '2018-04-04'),
(1, 'processing', '2018-04-02'),
(2, 'processing', '2018-04-01'),
(2, 'cancelled', '2018-04-07')
```

**Query 1**:

```
;WITH Ordered AS (
  SELECT id, status, date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date desc) AS rowNumber,
    LEAD(date) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date desc) AS prevDate
  FROM test
) 
SELECT 
    id, 
    MAX([1]) AS Operation_Latest,
    MAX([D1]) AS DaysElapsed_Prev1_Latest,
    MAX([2]) AS Operation_Prev1, 
    MAX([D2]) AS DaysElapsed_Prev2_Prev1,
    MAX([3]) AS Operation_Prev2, 
    MAX([D3]) AS DaysElapsed_Prev3_Prev2,
    MAX([4]) AS Operation_Prev3,
    MAX([D4]) AS DaysElapsed_Prev4_Prev3
 FROM 
 (SELECT id, rowNumber, status, 
      DATEDIFF(day, prevDate, date) AS daysSinceLast,
      'D' + CONVERT(varchar, rowNumber) AS DaysPivot
  FROM Ordered) AS p
 PIVOT
 (
   MAX(status) FOR rowNumber IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])
 ) AS pv1
 PIVOT
 (
   MAX(daysSinceLast) FOR daysPivot IN ([D1], [D2], [D3], [D4])
 ) AS pv2
GROUP BY id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2097b/1/0)**:

```
| id | Operation_Latest | DaysElapsed_Prev1_Latest | Operation_Prev1 | DaysElapsed_Prev2_Prev1 | Operation_Prev2 | DaysElapsed_Prev3_Prev2 | Operation_Prev3 | DaysElapsed_Prev4_Prev3 |
|----|------------------|--------------------------|-----------------|-------------------------|-----------------|-------------------------|-----------------|-------------------------|
|  1 |        cancelled |                        2 |            hold |                       1 |      processing |                       2 |      processing |                  (null) |
|  2 |        cancelled |                        6 |      processing |                  (null) |          (null) |                  (null) |          (null) |                  (null) |
```